# I'm tring to insert a form into the sql database, but nothing happens. the database is still empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a form submission web app, and everything worked until trying to insert into the database, the connection is working,but when it gets to the OnPost() method, nothing happens, i tried writing a console error in the onpost but still, nothing appears.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Proiectss.Pages.Clients
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        public ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
        public String errorMessage = "";
        public String successMessage = "";
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnPost method is being executed.");
            clientInfo.name = Request.Form["name"];
            clientInfo.email = Request.Form["email"];
            clientInfo.phone = Request.Form["phone"];
            clientInfo.adress = Request.Form["adress"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientInfo.name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientInfo.email) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientInfo.phone) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientInfo.adress))
            {
                errorMessage = "All the fields are required";
                return;
            }


            //salvam clientul in baza de date

            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=spital;Integrated Security=True";
                using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO clients " +
                        "(name, email, phone, adress) VALUES " +
                        "(@name, @email, @phone, @adress);";

                    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                        {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", clientInfo.name);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", clientInfo.email);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", clientInfo.phone);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adress", clientInfo.adress);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = "Error inserting data into the database: " + ex.Message;
                return; 
            }

            clientInfo.name = ""; clientInfo.email = ""; clientInfo.phone = ""; clientInfo.adress = "";
            successMessage = "New Client Added Correctly";

        }
    }
}
```

```
@page
@model Proiectss.Pages.Clients.CreateModel
@{
}

<br>
<h2>New Client</h2>

@if (Model.errorMessage.Length > 0)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade shadow" role="alert">
        <strong>@Model.errorMessage</strong>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"></button>
    </div>
}

<form method="POST">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="@Model.clientInfo.name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="@Model.clientInfo.email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="@Model.clientInfo.phone">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="@Model.clientInfo.adress">
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (Model.successMessage.Length > 0)
    {
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade shadow" role="alert">
                    <strong>@Model.successMessage</strong>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    } <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-3 d-grid">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 d-grid">
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/" role="button">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried to insert into the database, but nothing happens

Comment: "Nothing happens" is a bit of a non-starter.  In your browser, does the form post to the server?  In your debugger, is `OnPost()` invoked at all?

Comment: no , the OnPost() is not getting invoked at all, at least not with this  public void OnPost()
 {
    
     Console.WriteLine("OnPost method is being executed.");

     clientInfo.name = Request.Form["name"];
     clientInfo.email = Request.Form["email"];
     clientInfo.phone = Request.Form["phone"];
     clientInfo.adress = Request.Form["adress"];

Comment: Is the browser sending a POST request to the server?  What are the details of that request?  How specifically are you observing that the method isn't being invoked?  If the method isn't being invoked then **all** of the code within that method (and **most** of the markup on the page) is irrelevant to the problem and you can drastically reduce this to a [mcve] which can be replicated in a local environment to demonstrate.

Comment: the browser is sending a post method, with status 200 ok

Comment: And does the body of that request contain the values you expect from the form?  Is there anything in the body of the response?  Does the response contain a `Location` header for a redirect?  And how specifically are you observing that the method isn't being invoked?  Nobody here can debug your code on your computer for you, please provide the requested debugging information.

Comment: the request method sended is actually a GET  :" 
http://localhost:64036/761f26aab95140eead077372a9a3594a/browserLinkSignalR/negotiate?requestUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7111%2FClients%2FCreate&browserName=&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64)+AppleWebKit%2F537.36+(KHTML%2C+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2F120.0.0.0+Safari%2F537.36&browserIdKey=window.browserLink.initializationData.browserId&browserId=3b39-27fd&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1704457473906
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK
Remote Address:
[::1]:64036
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like you're *very confused* on what request(s) you're looking for or how to debug any of this.  You are encouraged to start with some introductory tutorials on Razor Pages, and start familiarizing yourself with your browser's debugging tools as well as the Visual Studio debugger.  Given the responses so far, it's entirely possible (even likely) that the `OnPost` method *is* being invoked and you're just not familiar with how to observe or debug what it's doing.

Comment: You may also consider not using `AddWithValue`, as it will make it more difficult to debug any issues with the SQL. Additionally, please review the documentation for [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) because the method returns a value.